# Is it possible to do a external hidden redirect?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm trying to redirect the URLS from our old site and server (`website.com`) to a new host, where the domain has not been updated yet pending administrative delays. As such, it's got some nasty URL (`username.hosting.com`) that I would like to get the stuff from.

Is this possible? I've tried:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?website\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://username.hosting.com/$1 [L,R]
```

But it keeps on **insisting to visibly rewriting the URL**, which is what I want to hide from the user.

Comment: You can't do this with a standard redirect. You would have to set your server as a proxy server and use mod_proxy, or do it "cheap" and use an `iframe`.

Answer (score 1):

See if the below helps:

`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)??website.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://username.hosting.com/$1 [PT,L,QSA]`